# WCF, SQLite, WPF. Клиент-серверное приложение C#. Несостыковка типов данных

Tags: wpf, sqlite, wcf

При добавление ссылки и создание экземпляра клиента возникает несостыковка типов данных, к примеру:
Из-за этого я не могу выполнить метод который отправит данные на сервер, к примеру:

```
WCF_Service.Model.User newUser = new WCF_Service.Model.User()
{
FName = "Олег",
Phone = "+79888888888"
}

client.AddUser(newUser).
```

Получаю ошибку
Невозможно преобразовать тип WCF_Service.Model.User в Service1Referense.User.

Атрибуты DataContract и DataMember я добавил ко всем полям и классам модели.
Подскажите как это реализовать.

Вот как расписан класс в WCF:

```
[DataContract]
[Table("Users")]
[Serializable]
public partial class User
{

    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    [Column("ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    
    [DataMember]
    [Column("FName")]
    public string FName { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember]
    [Column("Skype")]
    public string Skype { get; set; }
    
    
    [DataMember]
    [Column("Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember]
    [Column("Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember]
    [Column("Login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember]
    [Column("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Ну так по ошибке у вас пишет то, что у вас 2 разных класса `User`, а раз так, то о какой состыковке идет речь? Делайте тогда "конвертацию" из одного класса в другой.

Comment: конвертация невозможна.
Служба создает класс без полей.
А мне нужно, чтоб с полями. Я не знаю как это сделать.
Модель не переносится в клиентскую часть.

Comment: Почему невозможна? Делаете `new User() { Id = model.Id }` и так далее, перенося все данные в нужный вам класс, ну или используйте библиотеки по типу AutoMapper, который сделает это за вас, это стандартная практика переноса данных) Ну а так, вы больше ничего не сделаете, если у вас два совершенно разных класса.

Comment: Код класса User полученный по ссылке на службу не содержит полей.